# MVC3 - IgnoreRoute RegEX

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I can't seem to get MVC to ignore this route (throws an Controller not found if file doesn't exist - which happens occasionally and is expected if the generation isn't complete)

```
 /WebDirectory/signalFiles/52f23308-6d2d-40e6-9048-319e0539c83d.txt
```

I'm trying this right now in the Global.ASAX to eliminate the error

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{*signalstxt}", new { signalstxt = @".*/signalFiles/.*.txt" });
```

this matches perfectly in the RegEx tester but does nothing in the actual app

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way IIS 7 & MVC3 handle requests through the managed pipeline, it takes a [good deal of effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387500/iis-understand-static-files-in-mvc-as-dynamic-content) to prevent running static file requests through the routing engine. I've seen some evidence that moving the static files to a virtual directory outside of the web applications directory would have the desired effect, but haven't had a chance to test this for myself.

**edit**

clarification: the exception you are seeing is a normal part of MVC3 operation. It is how the handlers notify the IIS pipeline that it was unable to handle a request, thus invoking the next handler. You can prevent it from interfering with your debugging by enabling "just my code" in the Visual Studio Debug settings.